# Пунктуация в стихотворении и стилистика

Tags: пунктуация, стилистика

Помогите, пожалуйста. Есть подозрение, то запятые в скобках расставлены неверно.

---

Меня там ждут друзья,
Я должен им помочь(,)
И медлить мне нельзя,
Ведь скоро будет ночь!

---

– Ой, мама, силы нет...
Я что-то так устал, –
Сказал сынок в ответ(,)
И на скамью упал.

---

Как вам такая формулировка (смущает "проиграв в игре"):

"Как ты думаешь, как нужно себя вести, проиграв в игре?"

Comment: Какого рода «игра», или это фигура речи? Лучше это (про игру) сделать отдельным вопросом, вообще-то.

Comment: Вопрос задан после стихотворения, в котором ребенок проигрывает игру в футбол, психует, но потом "берет себя в руки", начинает упорно тренироваться и в финале становится сильным и уверенным в себе игроком. Но по "игрой" подразумевается любая игра, не только футбол.

Comment: Любая игра... Игры бывают индивидуальные, парные, командные. В футболе, если и проигрывает,  то вся команда. Про отдельного игрока так не говорят, — не принято. ===== Повторю: почему это не сделать отдельным вопросом?

Comment: А что с запятыми? На мой взгляд, они здесь не нужны.

Comment: А что с отдельным вопросом о «формулировке»? Она относится к пунктуации и стилистике стиха.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, пожалуйста, отметьте его [как принятый](/help/accepted-answer) (галочка рядом с ответом).

Answer (score 2):

Начну с последнего.

Вас смущает повтор корней? Кажется тавтологией? Это не так. Можно сыграть в игру, выиграть игру, проиграть игру. Наконец, есть же два известнейших названия книг Эрика Берна - «Игры, в которые играют люди» и «Люди, которые играют в игры»...

---

Теперь о запятых.

В первом предложении

---

*Меня там ждут друзья,*

*Я должен им помочь,*

*И медлить мне нельзя,*

*Ведь скоро будет ночь!*

---

запятая после "помочь" разделяет предложения с двумя основами: *я должен помочь* и *нельзя медлить*,

во втором предложении запятая поставлена неверно,

потому что предложение простое: *сынок сказал и упал.*

---

P. S. после коммента.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

> Все осталось жить на этой земле Только ты одна проиграла в этой игре.
>
> Как вы считаете, может быть, ЕС даже не мог выиграть в этой игре с
>   Украиной, так как он не так заинтересован в этом, как Россия?

Comment: Проиграть игру — да, но что вы скажете по поводу "проиграть в игре"?

Comment: М_Г, мне как-то не резануло слух... Однако погуглим и понаблюдаем частотность. Потом отчитаемся! )))

Comment: Нашлось кой-чего; слишком загугляться показалось ску-у-ушным - ограничусь пятью примерами, запихнув их в ответ!

Comment: Выражение разговорное, но не ошибка. Имеется в виду  проиграть -
 потерпеть неудачу в чем-н. (игре, споре, состязании, столкновении с кем-н.), поэтому возможно и "проиграл в игре", т.е. потерпел неудачу в игре, в процессе игры. Маленький нюанс: проиграл игру - важно, что всю игру проиграл, а проиграл в игре - возможно, что проиграл один из этапов  игры.

Comment: @Людмила Есть еще один нюанс, на мой взгляд (слух). Могу еще принять "проиграл *в какой-л.* игре", но режет слух просто "проиграл в игре". Это мое субъективное?

Answer (score 2):

**Я должен им помочь, и медлить мне нельзя.** — Запятая нужна, это сложносочиненное предложение.

**Сказал сынок в ответ и на скамью упал**. — Запятая не нужна, простое предложение, *сказал* и *упал* — однородные сказуемые.

Еще одно замечание. Не очень нравятся мне четыре семантически неоднородных
предложения, поставленные в ряд.

Я бы предпочел точку, разбивая их на две смысловые пары.

**Меня там ждут друзья, я должен им помочь. И медлить мне нельзя, ведь скоро будет ночь!**

Другой вариант. Я бы поставил тире перед последним простым предложением. Оно в какой-то мере является итогом предыдущих трех.

**Меня там ждут друзья, я должен им помочь, и медлить мне нельзя — ведь скоро будет ночь!**

Проиграть в игре -  неудачное выражение, на мой взгляд. Проиграть можно игру, а не в игре. По-моему, в игре обычно или побеждают, или терпят поражение, неудачу.

Comment: Скажите,пож-та, в «медлить мне нельзя» какое подлежащее и сказуемое?

Comment: См. ответ @GalinaAvanesova: основа — *нельзя медлить*, поясню: подлежащего нет.